# OnClick Event of EditButton in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the `OnClick` event of the `EditButton` in the `GridView`

```
protected void editclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Button EditButton = (Button)gvUserMaster.FindControl("edit_btn");
        tblAddEdit.Visible = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

But I am getting the Exception :

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'lblUserName' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

I tried using foreach loop but that too didn't work.

Comment: Could you show your ASPX code? The error message indicates some `lblUserName`.

Comment: Ok there was redundancy in lblUsername I solved that but can u how to get the row id of the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Use template field to add button
like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit"
            CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
            OnCommand="lnkEdit_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and in code behind :

```
protected void lnkEdit_Command(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e)
{
    id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    --add your code
}
```

you will get row index in id

Answer (score 0):

I solved by writing the edit function on the edit button click event and got the row id of the selected row.

```
int rindex = (((GridViewRow)(((Button)(sender)).Parent.BindingContainer))).RowIndex;
 Button EditButton = (Button)gvUserMaster.Rows[rindex].FindControl("btnEdit");
```

rindex give you the rowindex and EditButton give you the id of the selected row.